# ng-book 2 forms error

Tags: webpack, angular

So I'm following along in the new Ng-book 2 and I'm running into an error that prevents me from actively following along with the tut. I've sent the question to the authors, so once they respond I'll update this question with their answer. But for time being your help is very appreciated!

Basically, in order to run the forms and form validation examples I have to run the commands 'make install' and 'make dev'.

Make install works fine, but then I do make dev I get this error:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server
module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'optimist'
```

Upon looking into what optimist is, it's some outdated and non-supported node module. I think that this means is that the config file for webpack needs to be updated because it includes some references to it.

Like here:

```
var argv = require('optimist')
        // .alias('e','env').default('e','dev')
        // .alias('r','release').default('r', false)
        // .alias('m','minify')
        // .alias('t','hotComponents').default('t', false)
        .argv;
```

The question is, then, how do I update this?

Comment: Try just `npm i optimist`

Comment: Seems to have worked. I'm getting a bunch of different errors now though. Ugh.. this book is great but would be nice if it didn't have so many errors

Comment: Well you are aiming a moving target which is not stable enough. The examples maybe written against specific version and may not work if versions change, especially Angular2 versions.

Comment: @alexpods If you submit your answer as an answer I can give you credit. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this particular problem you can just do:

```
npm i optimist
```